# Magnific Popup - adding bottom bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, magnific-popup

Hi so I have a website with different tabs and in each tab there is around 2-5 images which I set up to popup on click and I was wondering is there a way to have a seperate bottom bar for each image depending on the tab selected I know how to do php config I just dont know how to add the bottom bar with maginific popup because only way to add something to bottom is to use title attribute please can someone help me!!

Example of bottom bar : https://gyazo.com/fb8039f8091e96a9d62bb89b6138be11

Example Code : [Code](//jsfiddle.net/5b01x6g2/51/)

```
Please Help Me!
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post code into the question itself.

Comment: @mhatch I have updated my code!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the mark-up of the Magnific popup by including the `markup` option in the `image` option, something like this:

```
$('.zoom-gallery').magnificPopup({
    ...,
    image: {
        ...,
        markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                  '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                  '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                  '<div class="custom-bottom-bar">'+
                    '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                    '<ul>'+
                      '<li>first list item</li>'+
                      '<li>things will likely need further CSS adjustments</li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                  '</div>'+
                '</div>'
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

By including a `.mfp-title` div, that will output the title attribute as usual, in this case just in a different context. Here is a fiddle with some CSS added: http://jsfiddle.net/5b01x6g2/52/